# sendmail relay server problems

Tags: email, smtp, port, sendmail

**<strike>Note: I've also posted this question on superuser, but i've decided to put it here too, since no one's really answering on superuser.</strike>**

<strike>Superuser link: https://superuser.com/questions/1106076/sendmail-relay-server-problems</strike>

So i have this internet provider called dna, that's only allowing communication on port 25 to their own smtp servers. So i tried the following in sendmail.mc: `define('SMART_HOST', 'smtp.dnainternet.fi')dnl`. But when i try to flush the mailqueue i get:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -q

Running /var/spool/mqueue/u6SC0Cqg013901 (sequence 1 of 7)
u6SC0Cqg013901: locked

Running /var/spool/mqueue/u6RDRTKX031454 (sequence 2 of 7)
u6RDRTKX031454: locked

Running /var/spool/mqueue/u6R9Fml7029261 (sequence 3 of 7)
<jcoatanea@gmail.com>... Connecting to smtp.dnainternet.fi. via relay...
<jcoatanea@gmail.com>... Deferred: Connection timed out with smtp.dnainternet.fi.
```

Which i think is because i need credentials to use the dna smtp servers, so how can i enter the credentials into the sendmail config.

**Edit:**

Traceroute gives me this:

```
traceroute smtp.dnainternet.fi
traceroute to smtp.dnainternet.fi (83.102.40.116), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.512 ms  0.824 ms  0.814 ms
 2  87-92-0-1.bb.dnainternet.fi (87.92.0.1)  3.006 ms  3.002 ms  3.301 ms
 3  esp2-tr2.dnaip.fi (62.78.123.155)  3.487 ms  3.574 ms  3.606 ms
 4  hel6-er2.dnaip.fi (62.78.104.15)  4.507 ms  4.391 ms  4.596 ms
 5  hel6-er1.dnaip.fi (62.78.118.138)  4.521 ms hel6-er1.dnaip.fi (62.78.117.55)  6.008 ms  4.780 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: Your error message indicates a simple **connection time-out** to (TCP port 25 on) smtp.dnainternet.fi, first resolve that connectivity problem, nothing indicates that you need to authenticate, you don't even reach that stage it seems.

Comment: @HBruijn see the edit.

Comment: @HBruijn it doesn't look like a connectivity error to me.

Comment: Your question is off topic on Superuser so you need to delete that one.

Comment: Have you called the ISP to ask them how you should access that server since it's their server and they would know best? This server does not appear to have an Open Relay as per http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3asmtp.dnainternet.fi&run=toolpage so it may be worth a shot to simply ask the ISP about this for a quick answer.

Comment: You can try a simple `telnet smtp.dnainternet.fi 25` to see if the port is open. If so you should at least get a 1 line header back saying what sort of smtp service it is.

Comment: I'm able to reach their server on ports 25, 465 and 587 without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

**If** your ISP block outgoing smtp connection (to port 25)
**then** try to connect to port 587 on the smart host.
[ smtp.dnainternet.fi accepts connections to port 587 ]

[Sendmail FAQ 3.39 : How do I send using an alternate port?](https://web.archive.org/web/20161126175659/https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/faq_ver_8_issues/#3.39)